# haskell std output stream problems

Tags: haskell, stdout

Consider this haskell code

```
import GHC
import GhcMonad

main = runGhc (Just "/usr/lib/ghc") $ do

  flags <- getSessionDynFlags
  setSessionDynFlags flags
  imps <- mapM parseImportDecl ["import Prelude"]
  setContext (map IIDecl imps)

  runStmt "putStrLn \"1\"" RunToCompletion
  liftIO $ putStrLn "2"
```

Which is compiled with `ghc -o a.out source_file.hs -package ghc`

If run from terminal it outputs

```
1
2
```

However if started as subprocess which stdout and stderr are redirected to main process - only `2` is captured from stdout. The question is what does `runStmt "putStrLn \"1\"" RunToCompletion` do? Does it start new thread/process? Which stream does it write to then?

Comment: You can https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace your program and see for yourself.

Comment: @NonNumeric Note `strace` can help detecting OS threads, but not Haskell (green) threads. In general, many Haskell threads run in a single OS thread.

Comment: @chi Yes, `strace` sees system calls only and won't catch runtime internal workings, be it its forkIO threads or something else, but it will answer the OP's question of whether a sub-process is started or not.